# Non XHR (non-AJAX) Post request from Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

There is one requirement to use an external service from within our Angular Application. The external service has its own User Interface. So, we have to redirect to the external service using a pure HTTP Post request on the given External Service's URL.

Is there a way to do non-AJAX post call from Angular so that the screen redirects to the external service webpage.

Comment: You can always create a FORM and submit to External Service URL

Comment: If you want to get data from an API, it's Ajax. If you want to redirect the user, you use `window.location`.

Comment: @trichetriche, but along with redirection I need to post some data. Like doing old school Form Post, where the browser redirects itself to the other url. I can't use window.location for the same, I think

Comment: Make an HTTP call, and on subscription, redirect to the page ?

Comment: The external service does not support AJAX Post.

Comment: You can use either window.location or use iframe to redirect but using this you need to form query string to pass data to the said url.

Comment: @NehalDamania how can external service know that he is receiving an ajax request? i think he can't. so what do you need to do? why you are saying that external service does not support ajax request?

Comment: @firegloves By doing a non-AJAX post the browser url changes to the url where the form is posted and the user can use the external service's page. I cannot simply redirect to their URL, they have a post handler. If I do Ajax call, how do I redirect to their Page. Further, it gives CORS and other errors, while doing normal AJAX request.

Comment: ok, so as suggested by Satpal you could make a simple html form without inputs, then submit it programmatically?

Comment: @firegloves yes trying the same. Will update with results

Comment: @firegloves, yes it is working fine

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will post my answer to help anyone in future

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is to dynamically create a form on fly and submit. I created a method in a Service class something like below to make it work. This method was then invoked from component. Created a helper method `createHiddenElement` as had many more parameters to be posted. Hope this helps someone.

```
  postToExternalSite(dataToPost: SomeDataClass): void {
    const form = window.document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "https://someexternalUrl/xyz");
    //use _self to redirect in same tab, _blank to open in new tab
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank"); 

    //Add all the data to be posted as Hidden elements
    form.appendChild(this.createHiddenElement('firstname', dataToPost.firstName));
    form.appendChild(this.createHiddenElement('lastname', dataToPost.lastname));

    window.document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
  }

  private createHiddenElement(name: string, value: string): HTMLInputElement {
    const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('name', name);
    hiddenField.setAttribute('value', value);
    hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    return hiddenField;
  }
```