# Angular Post to external server, display results in iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-httpclient

So I am integrating my angular application into a payment gateway, in certain instances there is an additional security check required by the payment processor. For anyone interested, its a [3D Secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-D_Secure) implementation.

I can perform the post request no problem, but the value returned from my provider is simply....

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redirecting...</title>
```

I was hoping it would return full html that I could just render in a modal, no such luck.

So I tried to create an iframe to post into and handle this (like the old school days) but I can't get this to work. My code so far...

Component

```js
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('form') postForm: ElementRef;
    private MD: any;
    private PaReq: any;
    private TermUrl: any;
    private demoEndpoint: any;
    @ViewChild('threedsModal', { static: true }) private threedsModal;
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.demoEndpoint = 'www.example.com/post/'
        this.MD = 'foo';
        this.PaReq = 'bar';
        this.TermUrl = 'www.myexample.com/response';


    }
    onLoad() {
        console.log('onLoad triggered.');
    }
   // Called from another part of the code when we need to perform the POST
    submitForm(){

        // values are custom encoded, not needed to show for example
        const myParams = new HttpParams({encoder: new HttpUrlEncodingCodec()})
            .set('MD', this.MD)
            .set('PaReq', this.PaReq)
            .set('TermUrl', this.TermUrl);
        this.http.post(this.demoEndpoint, myParams, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

        return true;
    }

}
```

Then in my template:

```html
 <iframe class="custom-frame" #frame width="400" height="400" id="frame" name="frame" 
          frameborder="0" [src]="demoEndpoint | safeResourceUrl" (load)="onLoad()"></iframe>

<form target="frame" action="demoEndpoint| safeResourceUrl" #form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MD" value={{MD}} id="MD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value={{PaReq}} id="PaReq" />
    <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value={{TermUrl}} id="TermUrl" />
</form>
```

But this iframe simply renders "Unable to determine the request"

If I perform the POST request manually in postman, in renders the correct HTML, but the response from my httpPOST in console just shows Re-directing.

So my question, how can I achieve this in an iframe and render the correct response?

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268351/how-to-post-traditional-form-into-iframe-within-an-angular-4-app) helped me somewhat

Comment: Why is post only returning redirecting? Sounds like the action to that response is deeper into the api. Sounds like the server is redirecting withot a 302 response code. That's not a normal redirect.

Comment: This api is honestly the worst thing I have ever coded against, this was my thoughts as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the help of anyone in the future, this was fairly easy with the [help of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985353/non-xhr-non-ajax-post-request-from-angular)

```
  // create a form for the post request
  const form = window.document.createElement('form');
  form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
  form.setAttribute('action', 'http://post.example.com');
  // use _self to redirect in same tab, _blank to open in new tab
  // form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  form.setAttribute('target', 'threedframe');

  // Add all the data to be posted as Hidden elements
  form.appendChild(this.createHiddenElement('MD', 'foo'));
  form.appendChild(this.createHiddenElement('PaReq', 'bar'));
  form.appendChild(this.createHiddenElement('TermUrl','https://dump.example.com'));
  console.log(form);
  window.document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();

  // create the form
  private createHiddenElement(name: string, value: string): HTMLInputElement {
    const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('name', name);
    hiddenField.setAttribute('value', value);
    hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    return hiddenField;
  }
```

Then setup an iframe in my template:

```
 <iframe class="custom-frame" id="three-d-frame"  width="430" height="450" frameborder="0" name="threedframe">
```

Comment: Ya like we always say, easy when you know how, impossible when you don't.... Have a good day!

Comment: @crooksey, thanks for solution, it worked for me in all browsers except in iOS devices (or safari browsers). could you please help on this.

Comment: @KishoreKonangi above solution works for me in Safari, both desktop and IOS, so not sure?

Comment: @crooksey, after additional effort, found that the issue is happening due to the redirection url (where my redirection url is inturn redirecting to another website..) at this point i'm getting "network connection lost" message.

Comment: I am using your code but in Iframe I dont get anything it is simply blank document. any ideas?

Comment: Share the code? Ill take a look